# Detect the percentage of a color in an image using GraphicsMagick

Tags: graphicsmagick

I'm looking to try and detect what proportion of an image is white using GraphicsMagick.

The reasoning behind this is I need to provide feedback to a user, saying that they should upload an image with a transparent background when the background is white, rather than upload an image with a pure white background.

I've looked through the [documentation](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html) but I'm not quite sure where to start on this one.

Thanks